# Tagging and pushing Docker image changes digest

Tags: docker, github-actions, google-container-registry

Pulling, tagging, and then pushing a Docker image we produce in a Github actions flow is causing a new image with a new digest to be pushed, rather than simply tagging the existing image.

First, we build the image using the newish v2 of the Docker build-push action (https://github.com/docker/build-push-action)

```yaml
jobs:
  build-push:
    name: Build and push docker image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to GCR
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: gcr.io
          username: _json_key
          password: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
      - id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          tags: gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag
          push: true
          target: build
          build-args: |
            NPM_TOKEN=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Then, in a separate workflow later we pull that image (`gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag`) down and add new tags.

```yaml
jobs:
  tag-image:
    name: Tag image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to GCR
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: gcr.io
          username: _json_key
          password: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
      - run: |
          docker pull gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag
          docker tag gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag gcr.io/our-project/foo:new-tag
          docker push gcr.io/our-project/foo:new-tag
```

After pushing up `new-tag`, I would expect our registry to contain one image digest with the `initial-tag` and `new-tag` on it. Instead, this creates a new image digest with just `new-tag` on it.

```
Digest: sha256:abc123
Tags: gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag

Digest: sha256:def456
Tags: gcr.io/our-project/foo:new-tag
```

In addition, if we now pull and add a tag (say `latest`) to `new-tag`, it will NOT create a new image digest

```
Digest: sha256:abc123
Tags: gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag

Digest: sha256:def456
Tags: gcr.io/our-project/foo:new-tag, gcr.io/our-project/foo:latest
```

As a workaround, we have found that pushing the image name without tags correctly assigns the tag to the existing digest.

```sh
docker pull gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag
docker tag gcr.io/our-project/foo:initial-tag gcr.io/our-project/foo:new-tag
docker push gcr.io/our-project/foo
```

Comment: Asking since it's not clear from the question; Is this behavior specific to GCR or does it happen on other registries as well (for ex. DockerHub) which would indicate standard Docker behavior?

Also, please take a look at this thread, which might be of use to you: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/676#issuecomment-597504724

Comment: @AlbertoPau I have not tried with another registry asides from GCR. I will have to see what the crane tool mentioned in that thread does under the covers or see if we can use it for our workflow. Thanks!

Comment: Just hit the same issue in harbor and I am trying figure out is it expected (comes from some standard) or just a bug?

Answer (score 1):

`crane cp` will copy images efficiently and retaining the digest value

https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/doc/crane_copy.md

Answer (score 1):

you can export docker image and push like this.
then docker image digest does not change whenever you tag more.

```
- name: build docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
  with:
    context: .
    file: 'Dockerfile'
    load: true
    tags: |
      ${{ steps.tag-container-image.outputs.TAG_A }}
      ${{ steps.tag-container-image.outputs.TAG_B }}
      ${{ steps.tag-container-image.outputs.LATEST }}

- name: push docker image
  run: |
    docker push ${{ steps.tag-container-image.outputs.TAG_A }}
    docker push ${{ steps.tag-container-image.outputs.TAG_B }}
    docker push ${{ steps.tag-container-image.outputs.LATEST }}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I thought that `load` was the key step, but the action docs tell me it's merely an alias for type docker 

Comment: This example makes all the tags when the container is built, so it's not pulling the image and promoting it. it is suitable if you know all the tags you want and you want them in the current workflow job.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect a docker image, the image id and the repo digests are not the same thing. If I take an image in multiple repositories and run `docker inspect` I see multiple digests:

```json
    {
        "Id": "sha256:8c2c38aa676e97e57b4c8385bbcdcb240a933fafcc5f6cc508d2a3a005b24cb8",
        "RepoTags": [
            "docker/desktop-vpnkit-controller:v2.0",
            "hubproxy.docker.internal:5000/docker/desktop-vpnkit-controller:v2.0"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "docker/desktop-vpnkit-controller@sha256:b5bcb3a7172ae44d3a1df2e74a1b4d4e10d5562efe1d3c9197b23b383de70a86",
            "hubproxy.docker.internal:5000/docker/desktop-vpnkit-controller@sha256:b5bcb3a7172ae44d3a1df2e74a1b4d4e10d5562efe1d3c9197b23b383de70a86"
        ],
```

The ID field will be the same, which means the FS layers will be the same. It is not a different image.